# systemd failed to unmount during shutdown

Tags: debian, systemd

At first my machine was giving the following message while shut down.

```
Job usere1000.service/stop running (59s / no Limit): User job app-gnome-yandexx2ddisk-1908.scope/stop running (58s / no limit)...
```

Then I set `KillUserProcesses=yes` is `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`. Now the machine shutdown first but give error

```
Failed unmounting media-ismail-SSDWorking.mount - /media/ismail/SSDWorking.
```

Just to mention, my `Yandex.Disk` that sync via a daemon is located in this ssd (/media/ismail/SSDWorking) which was giving message earlier.

Maybe because my system is not killing the process before unmounting (I am not sure).

**Update 1:**

I found `/run/systemd/generator/media-ismail-SSDWorking.mount` with the following conternt:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
After=blockdev@dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-SSDWorking.target

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-label/SSDWorking
Where=/media/ismail/SSDWorking
Options=nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show
```

I think if I can add `app-gnome-yandexx2ddisk-1908.scope` in `After=` via `systemd-fstab-generator` **for unmount** then it might solve the problem.

**Update 2:**

```
$ systemd-umount /dev/sda1
$ journalctl -xe
 A stop job for unit media-ismail-SSDWorking.mount has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3897.
Jul 07 12:38:22 debian-i5 umount[10089]: umount: /media/ismail/SSDWorking: target is busy.
Jul 07 12:38:22 debian-i5 systemd[1]: media-ismail-SSDWorking.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ An n/a= process belonging to unit media-ismail-SSDWorking.mount has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 32.
Jul 07 12:38:22 debian-i5 systemd[1]: Failed unmounting media-ismail-SSDWorking.mount - /media/ismail/SSDWorking.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit media-ismail-SSDWorking.mount has finished
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3897 and the job result is failed.
```

**Update 3:**

If I run `yandex-disk stop`, then `systemd-mount /dev/sda1`, it simply unmount. So the issue is, the system is not stopping `yandex-disk` before trying to unmount.

**Update 4:**

I have run the following:

```
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/run-before-shutdown.service << END
[Unit]
Description=Run my custom task at shutdown
Requires=network.target
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=reboot.target shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=ismail
Group=ismail
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/yandex-disk stop'
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
END

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start run-before-shutdown.service
sudo systemctl enable run-before-shutdown.service
```

Still getting error:

```
Failed unmounting media-ismail-SSDWorking.mount - /media/ismail/SSDWorking.
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this for months now and I even filed a bug report: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/26304 Too bad no one particularly cares.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have upvoted the issue. Hopefully someone will notice that.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov please check update 3 in the question.

Comment: Looks like the bug report is valid, I wrote *"How is it even possible if systemd kills everything prior to umount'ing?"* - looks like systemd doesn't (always) do that.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov yes I agree with you. We should not have to find and stop services before shutdown. However, I just pointed this out so that we can have workarounds till the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. The issue was resolved after I introduced yandex-disk to systemd.

```
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/yandex-disk.service << END
[Unit]
Description=Yandex Disk Service
After=network.target
RequiresMountsFor=/media/ismail/SSDWorking

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ismail
Group=ismail
ExecStart=/usr/bin/yandex-disk start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/yandex-disk stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
END

sudo systemctl start yandex-disk
sudo systemctl enable yandex-disk
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```